In tetris game the row doesn't clear like a tetris game and scoring system is broken
I had created a game where one could play Tetris from the command line using Python and the curses module. Everything was good but I am stuck on a function which is the score_and_clear(board, score) function in the code below. The function is one function block above the main() function.
Github link: termino_tetris
Code:
'''
A code snippet from termino_tetris.py in the repository: https://www.github.com/rafibuilds/termino_tetris
'''
import curses # The main module needed for this game to work
import time # Time-related functions for the smooth animation of the game
import random # To randomize the blocks in the game
import sys # Sytem handling
import copy # To copy the 2d list effectively

# Game Constants
BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT = 10, 20 # The tetris board width and height
BLOCK_CHAR = "X" # This is the character that will make the block or the tetromino
BOARD_CHAR = "O" # This is the character that will make the board

# Shapes of the blocks
SHAPES = [
    [[1, 1, 1, 1]], # Straight-line block

    [[1, 1], # Squre block
     [1, 1]],

    [[1, 1, 1], # T-block
     [0, 1, 0]],

    [[1, 1, 0], # Z-block
     [0, 1, 1]],

    [[0, 1, 1], # S-block
     [1, 1, 0]],

    [[1, 0], # L-block
     [1, 0],
     [1, 1]],

    [[0, 1], # Reverse L-block
     [0, 1],
     [1, 1]],
]

# Game level
LEVEL = 0.27

def create_new_block(shapes):
    '''Generates a shape and color for the block RANDOMLY'''
    # Initialize the colors. 0 is reserved for black and white color pair
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_YELLOW, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_BLUE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(5, curses.COLOR_CYAN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(6, curses.COLOR_MAGENTA, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    # Retrurn a random shape and the color
    return random.choice(shapes), curses.color_pair(random.randint(1, 6))

def draw_board(window, board):
    '''
    Draws the board on the screen
    -----------------------------
    board[y][x][0] is the char
    board[y][x][1] is the color
    '''
    for y in range(BOARD_HEIGHT): # Go through every row of the board
        for x in range(BOARD_WIDTH): # Go through every column of the row
            if board[y][x][0] == BOARD_CHAR:
                window.addstr(y, x, BOARD_CHAR) # If it is not a block char, then no color
            elif board[y][x][0] == BLOCK_CHAR:
                window.addstr(y, x, BLOCK_CHAR, board[y][x][1]) # If it is a block char, then there will be color

def make_board_list(rows, cols, char):
    '''
    Makes the board data structure which is a 2D list
    -------------------------------------------------
    width = cols
    height = rows
    '''
    board_data_list = []
    # Create the board data structure
    for _ in range(rows):
        board_data_list.append([(char, None)] * cols) # (char, None); None is replacement for the color
    return board_data_list

def draw_block(board, block, blocky, blockx, color):
    '''Puts the block in the board data structure'''
    # Update the landed blocks on the board
    for row, part in enumerate(block):
        for col, piece in enumerate(part):
            if piece == 1:
                board[blocky + row][blockx + col] = (BLOCK_CHAR, color)
            elif piece == 0: # No need to put that on the board
                continue
    return board

def score_and_clear(board, score):
    '''Clears the rows and scores, if all the chars are BLOCK_CHAR'''
    # Take note of which rows to clear
    rows_to_be_cleared = []
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(board):
        if all(item[0] == BLOCK_CHAR for item in row):
            rows_to_be_cleared.append(row_idx)

    # Clear the identified rows from the board
    for row_idx in reversed(rows_to_be_cleared):
        board.pop(row_idx)
        # Insert a new empty row at the top
        board.insert(0, [(BOARD_CHAR, None)] * BOARD_WIDTH)

    # Increase the score based on the number of cleared rows
    if rows_to_be_cleared:
        score += len(rows_to_be_cleared)

    return score, board

if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)

The intended thing for the score_and_clear() function to do is whenever rows match in character that is BLOCK_CHAR, then clear the row and update the scoreboard. In the function that I implemented, the rows get cleared, but the score goes crazy and doesn't stop incrementing. I need the function to behave properly like a Tetris game would (clearing all rows that are the same, and the score should increment by one for each row cleared).
Things I did to make it work:
I tried using copy.deepcopy , I used AI to give me a better-optimized code but nothing worked. One thing did was that I started from the bottom row and went up and that worked. What I mean is suppose the bottom row is filled and 2 other rows on top of the bottom row are also filled then it would clear from the bottom to the top in a satisfactory order and Tetris-like. But suppose that the bottom was not filled but the second to the bottom row was filled then it would do nothing.

Please narrow down your code to the Minimal, Reproducible Example

I made the code smaller. Hope it is ok now.
